# Deserialize JSON into different classes using Reflection

Tags: c#, json, reflection, deserialization

I am working on windows phone 8.1 application. I am working with REST API and the the api return me JSON data.
I want to create a method such that each time I call the API, I just send the type of class on which it is to be deserialized as a parameter and I get the deserialized data into an object of that model. My current code looks like this:

```
public static async Task GetAPIData(Type referanceModel, string serviceUrl)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var responce = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(serviceUrl));
        JArray arr = JArray.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

        foreach (JObject obj in arr.Children<JObject>())
        {
            JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            settings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore;

            var rcvdData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<referanceModel>(obj.ToString(), settings);


            //var method = typeof(JsonConvert).GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredMethods("DeserializeObject").ToList()[5].MakeGenericMethod(ReferanceModel);


            //var rcvd = method.Invoke(null, new object[] { obj.ToString(), settings });
        }

    }
```

The above code shows me the error that referanceModel is a variable. I tried the commented code also but it doesn't work too.

The two classes are: AllvehData and AllDevicesData.  Both of these classes are inside a singleton class called ThisUserClass with the instance of ThisUser

```
public class AllVehData
{
    public string Colour { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string model { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }


 }


 public class AllDevicesData
{
    bool has_tracking_device { get; set; }
    int drive_type_name_string_id { get; set; }
    public int vehicle_status { get; set; }
    public int cargo_capacity { get; set; }
    public int fuel_capacity { get; set; }
}
```

I searched a lot on the topic and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967618/deserialize-json-to-class-manually-with-reflection) but failed to understand. I need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you don't need the generic overload `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<>(string, JsonSerializerSettings)`. Instead use the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string, Type, JsonSerializerSettings)` overload and do:

```
var rcvdData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(obj.ToString(), referanceModel, settings);
```

When you use generics - either class or method - you MUST pass an actual type in the place of a generic parameter as opposed of a variable of type `Type`. This is the reason you get compile time error. E.g. in order to initialize a list of strings you cannot do:

```
var theStringVar = string.Empty;
var myList1 = new List<theStringVar>(); // Here we get the compile time error.

// OR

var theTypeVar = typeof(string);
var myList2 = new List<theTypeVar>(); // That won't work either.
```

Instead you need to specify the `string` type explicitly:

```
var myList3 = new List<string>(); // This works just fine.
```

Comment: @BozhdarStoinev Could you please tell me how would I call the method.

Comment: Just follow the example... what problem you facing?

Comment: I added your piece of code to the Json part, The issue is it doesn't updates the value into rcvdData. The rcvdData becomes an object of the AllVehData class with all null values.

Comment: In this case the `obj.ToString()` doesn't produces a JSON string which corresponds to the structure of the `AllVehData`.

Comment: Yes that solved out. i was using ThisUserClass.ThisUser.AllVehData.GetType() as a method parameter instead of typeof(ThisUserClass.ThisUser.AllVehData)